# Magento move search result

Tags: magento

For some reason when somebody performs a search on my site the search results do not display underneath the search box, they appear on the far left of the screen.

Any ideas of what file this would be configured in?

Let me correct myself it's not the search results but the search suggestions

Answer (score 0):

I can't offer a direct solution to your problem, but turning on template hints might point you in the right direction.  In the Admin, go to System > Configuration,  Select your store view from the scope drop down at the top left.  Unless you're running multi-store, or have changed the name of the default store it'll be called "Default Store View".  Then scroll down to "Developer" and open up the "Debug" section.  Turn on both Template Path Hints" and "Add Block Names to Hints".  This will add a div with a red border around each template in your layout and a heading which includes the name of the template.  It will liklely completely screw up your page layout, but will show you which template generated every tag on the page and help you track down the issue.

The [DeveloperToolbar](http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/MageWorld/extension/2271/mw_developertoolbar) extension makes turning this on/off quickly much easier, but I wouldn't recommend deploying it to a production site.

Alan Storm's indispensable [CommerceBug](http://store.pulsestorm.net/products/commerce-bug) is another tool which is very handly for tracking down front end issues.  CommerdeBug can show you the layout handles and the aggregate layout XML used to generate the current page.  Both of which are useful for determing why a specific block was (or wasn't) included.

Answer (score 0):

So in case anybody else runs into this or wants to move where their search suggestions display it is in styles.css  under .searchautocomplete.